# android retrofit get request @Path error

Tags: android, api, get, retrofit

I'm stuck with weird problem with GET request in android when I implemented request with retrofit.

I implemented this get request method and it worked alright.

this get request work perfectly

[image: this get request work perfectly]

then I decided that I need to dynamically change it in activity when i want it.

[image: get request in interface]

and when I pass to this method same exact URL this is how it looks in activity

[this is how it looks in activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A20cs.png)

In return I receive only error, that looks like this.

> Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found,
>   url=https://api.github.com/repos%2Ftempestme%2Fandroid_dictophone%2Fcommits

I can't really figure out where to look for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out what's the problem.
You can't pass url with slash (/) to get method, @Path receive it only like this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwpZn.png)